# How to retrieve mysql tables and store in hdfs file system

Tags: spring, hibernate, hadoop, hdfs

This is a very basic question for you, but i am new to spring and hibernate technologies. Can anyone suggest me which tool can be used to fetch mysql tables and store in HDFS file system(**here i am using sqoop to store mysql tables into hdfs**). But the dynamic implementation of this application i am not getting. I could not able to get what to use and how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear try elaborating

Comment: My task is i have write a program in which i have to dump MySQL data into HDFS file system. This is done using sqoop ok , now i have to develop a project with server configurations i.e., the mysql server is different and hadoop server is different. So for this I thought that there is requirement of spring and hibernate. So here my exact question is what exact technologies to be used to use these big data projects. As I am new to this spring, hibernate and big data tools I am unable to decide how to develop a project on this.